# LINQ Query for below table

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq

Table data:

| Id_Org_hierarchy | Hierarchy_Name | Parent_Id_Org_hierarchy |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | OGt | 0 |
| 2 | NHT | 1 |
| 3 | BATCH 1 | 2 |
| 3 | Voice | 1 |

I need result Like Below:

Batch1(NHT,OGT)

Details :
Id_Org_hierarchy column value is present in Parent_Id_Org_hierarchy and so on

its a tree struct format data.
can any one help me for this I have no idea how to achieve result.

Expecting this result **Batch1(NHT,OGT)**

Comment: Do you mean that you are searching for the ancestors of Batch1, including Batch1? Do we know how many levels there will be in total?

Comment: EF Core does not support recursive queries. You can fetch the whole table into memory and let the EF perfrom the fix up or use the from sql approach when you provide custom query.

Comment: the level is dynamic

Comment: Probably best to write a recursive CTE as a `VIEW` in SQL and query that view using EF.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use multiple LINQ queries or entity framework calls that each finds a parent of the element, like this:

```
current = initial; // initial is the very first item, Batch1 in this case
while ((current != null) && (current.Parent_Id_Org_hierarchy > 0)) {
    current = dbo.Where(item => item.Id_Org_hierarchy == current.Parent_Id_Org_hierarchy);
    if (current != null) myList.Add(current);
}
```

and then you can generate the string you wanted by putting `initial`'s `Hierarchy_name` before the paranthesis and then wrap a paranthesis around the comma-separated concatenation of the `Hierarchy_name` values of `myList` via

```
string.Join(",", myList.Select(item => item.Hierarchy_name))
```